# Operate on pandas groupby object in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar','cat'] * 3,
             'B': ['i','who','he','am','are','said','satya','you','hello'],
             'C': [5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9,12,23,45]})
df
Out[47]: 
A      B   C
0  foo      i   5
1  bar    who   2
2  cat     he   3
3  foo     am   4
4  bar    are   6
5  cat   said   9
6  foo  satya  12
7  bar    you  23
8  cat  hello  45
```

I am grouping them as below:

```
g = df.groupby('A')
for name, group in g:
     print(name)
     print(group)
```

getting o/p as:

```
bar
     A    B   C
1  bar  who   2
4  bar  are   6
7  bar  you  23
cat
     A      B   C
2  cat     he   3
5  cat   said   9
8  cat  hello  45
foo
     A      B   C
0  foo      i   5
3  foo     am   4
6  foo  satya  12
```

So what I need to do is I want to iterate over each group and again for each group I will iterate (i have no idea) over columns and concat the values at column `B` so that i can get something like

```
bar = who are you
cat = he said hello
foo = i am satya
```

I can't do a `agg` function on that. Can anyone suggest how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC you can `groupby` on `A` and then `apply` a lambda to `join` the string values:

```
In [185]:
df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(' '.join)

Out[185]:
A
bar      who are you
cat    he said hello
foo       i am satya
Name: B, dtype: object
```

Comment: @EdChum-great help..problem solved..Btw can i ask something on this regards which i have not mentioned in the question...

Comment: No one can stop you from asking, we can only choose whether to respond

Comment: Actually i have some filenames in place of strings in column B. So if i want to read each csv file for each group and append them .how can i achieve that..need your help!!

Comment: you can just iterate over the row values and call `pd.read_csv` or whatever please try it and if you get a problem post a new question